# When using Visual Studios 2012 for coding in C++, how do you autocomplete code selected in IntelliSense?

Tags: c++, c, autocomplete, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

When using IntelliSense, it would usually show up functions, members, and etc. in the dialog box. Usually at the very top of the dialog box, IntelliSense would automatically select the most relevent C++ code that fits what the user typed.

I want the IntelliSense to help me autocomplete the word I was typing, but whenever I press Enter key, it would just insert a new line, and not autocomplete it for me.

The only workaround for me is to press Down key, and then press Enter, in order to achieve this. Are there any other methods of making this process easier? It's annoying for me not being able to autocomplete C++ codes when pressing Enter key.

Comment: You might find [this somewhat informative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @WhozCraig That is for Visual Studios 2005, 2008, 2010, and .NET 2003.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 how correct you are. The [Using Intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b(v=VS.110).aspx) document for VS2012 is also available, and interestingly, they *did* change the default for Complete Word to ctrl-space. Bummer Sibrajas deleted his answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig That doesn't help for those who actually have IMEs that overrides the CTRL+SPACE hotkey. TAB is an optimal solution that also works around that problem.

Comment: So the IME-hotkey configuration is apparently as flexible as VS2012's Intellisense Complete-Word config? Lovely. No finger pointing there at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig Speaking of which, for IntelliSense to complete word, it tells us that TAB can be used in both Completion Mode and Suggestion Mode. This is probably what Sergey said about reading the help file, but inaccurately, it is for Visual Studios 2010.

Comment: I even checked the SmartCommitMemberListOnEnter registry setting. no dice there either. However, I did just check my VS2012, and I can finish an suggestion with Tab or ctrl-space, but there is nowhere visible that I can find to alter either. Why do I feel like I just got "metro'd" by Microsoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, press TAB key to autocomplete.